# breadcrumbs bug in ie issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my html code.

```
 <div style="float:left; width:510px;"><span><a disabled="disabled" style="color:White;text-decoration:none;">MY FIELD</a></span></div>
```

In Firefox "MY FIELD" text displays in white. But in IE it display on grey because of disabled. I have tried inline style. It works fine. But I have lot of files. Is it possible to change in css or some other way. I have attached the screenshot for ie issue. Thanks.

[image: My field / Play-by-Play]

Comment: Why do you use an `a`-tag if you don't want to uses it?

Comment: The `disabled` attribute is for `input`, `select` and `textarea` elements only, and not `a` elements. Perhaps use `span` with a "disabled" clas` instead of `a`, and avoid these issues.

Comment: Ok. Sure. I will remove the a tag. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to separate style from markup (for readability, maintainability, etc.). So, place your styling into a separate css file. Another thing you might want to change is the span around your anchor. The other way around is better. Also, the disabled property is for input elements only. In your case, it could look something like:

html:

```
<div>
    <a href="#">
        <span>MY FIELD</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

css:

```
div {
   float: left;
   width: 510px;
}

a {
   text-decoration: none;
}

a span {
   color: #fff;
}
```

I don't know why you have a span, but in this example you can do without. Of course you should move the color style to the anchor selector in that case. Weird thing in your code is...why use an anchor, if you do not use it for anything?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use jQuery to iterate over the elements with the attribute "disabled" sert to "disabled" and then set the style

```
$('a[disabled=disabled]').each(function(){
   this.style.color = "White";
})
```

In this way you don't need to modify a lot of files but you just use this function

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/wZbrF/

Comment: Looks fine to me, so I gave you an upvote to counter the downvote.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
var x = $('span a').attr('disabled')
alert(x);
if (x == 'disabled') {
    $('span a').attr("style","color:#fff");
}​
```

fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/huFaG/

Comment: Please check fiddle link it's working fine. if you find any mistakes on my code. please let me know

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but as a heads-up, your code only checks the first span-a's disabled value, but changes all of them; I'm guessing that's not what you want (or the OP for that matter).